# Деплой .netcore 1.0 app на Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Подскажите как задеплоить .net core 1.0 WebApp приложение на ubuntu в продакшен?

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html

Comment: @kmv я немного не понял каким образом работать через сокет kestrel? Он у меня впринципе не создаётся, либо не туда смотрю. И к тому же при перезапуске OS, приложение не поднимается

Comment: у них оказывается документация не обновлена https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/1275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом по этой ссылке все достаточно подробно расписано (docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html).
Мои шаги были следующими (Ubuntu 16.04):

1. Установить .net core, если не установлено;
2. Загрузить бинарники приложения на prod сервер, проверьте, что все стартует. Т.к. сервер разворачивается на Ubuntu, то нужно использовать Kestrel:

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup.Startup>()
                .Build();
```

3. В статье, указанной выше, рекомендуют использовать nginx. Пока asp.net не очень дружит с ssl и прочими штуками, а nginx - может. Поэтому ставим его. К тому же можно настроить нормальную маршрутизацию:
       1. Install: sudo apt-get install nginx
       2. Start: sudo service nginx start
       3. Check: sudo service nginx status
4. В nginx.config (/etc/nginx/nginx.config) настраиваем маршрутизацию:

location /test/gateway/ 
  {

```
                    rewrite /test/gateway/(.*) /$1  break;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9595;
            }
```

В proxy_pass вы указывается путь к вашему приложению. Я пока на одной машине разворачиваю и тестовое приложение, и production. Поэтому использую разные URL для их доступа.

```
rewrite /test/gateway/(.*) /$1  break;
```

Эта команда изменяет url, убирая /test/gateway/. Таким образом, доступ к тестовому и боевому сервер отличаются только во внешнем url, внутри приложения вносить изменения не нужно.

5. Сделаем так, чтобы приложение загружалось при старте и перезагружалось при падении. Для этого используем systemctl. В /etc/systemd/system создаем файл app_name.service со следующим содержимым:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gateway server for StreetFlow.

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /etc/bt/st.gateway/GatewayServer.dll

WorkingDirectory=/etc/bt/st.gateway
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Мы указываем, какую команду нужно выполнить, нужно ли запускать при ошибке. Так же можно указать зависимости, скажем, от postgresql или nginx.
После создания сервиса нужно выполнить две команды:
sudo systemctl enable your_app
sudo systemctl start your_app
Иногда после изменения конфига сервис может не запуститься. Это лечится командой
sudo systemctl daemon-reload.

Поздравляю, ваше приложение развернуто!